# mpdf7 and concurrent use of temp directory

Tags: php, mpdf

I want to use global system /tmp directory for temporary files of mpdf.
So I set this options:

```
  $optionsMpdf = [
    'tempDir' => '/tmp',
    ..
  ];
  $mpdf=new \Mpdf\Mpdf($optionsMpdf);
```

It ran, but I've seen a lot of warnings like this:

> PHP Warning:  unlink(/tmp/<nameOfFile>): Operation not permitted
>   in <pathToMpdf7>/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Cache.php on line 95

Looking at the code, I found that it tries to delete all files from /tmp folder, most of which it does not have the rights to.

Now I'm wondering about the right way to use Mpdf7 and avoid this problem.
First thing I thought is to create a folder inside /tmp and give it to mpdf:

```
  $optionsMpdf = [
    'tempDir' => '/tmp/mpdf',
    ..
  ];
```

My question now is: are there better ways to do this? I'm missing something?

I'm also wondering if there can be other problems if one runs php mpdf from root without checking this behavior. Isn't it better to manage all of this inside mpdf, deleting just the files created?

First version of my question was also related to possible concurrent problems, but I'm seeing now that they've been avoided deleting file older than 3600 seconds. In Cache.php source file I find:

```
public function clearOld()
{
    $iterator = new DirectoryIterator($this->basePath);
    /** @var \DirectoryIterator $item */
    foreach ($iterator as $item) {
        if (!$item->isDot()
                && $item->isFile()
                && !$this->isDotFile($item)
                && $this->isOld($item)) {
            unlink($item->getPathname());
        }
    }
}
```

The procedure isOld checks last modification time of the file to delete and proceed if it's older than 3600 seconds.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you really intend to use a system-wide temporary files directory, at least use a dedicated subdirectory:

```
$optionsMpdf = [
    'tempDir' => '/tmp/mpdf',
];
```

I'd rather use a dedicated directory closer to the source code for each project using mPDF - the autocleaning of old temporary files will then not collide with other possible instances of mPDF.

---

Side note: it's always better to use [`sys_get_temp_dir`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php) function to determine system temporary directory.

Comment: /tmp/mpdf is just what I suggested as first solution and sys_get_temp_dir function returns /tmp on my system. If I use the same directory for each project, what does it happen if I launch two instances from the same project?

Comment: You _may_ run into a race condition when first instance cleans old temporary files and the second counts on them to be present. Probability of this happening is the bigger the more instances use the same temp directory, however not very big.

Comment: Yes, that's my concern. I'm wondering it's good to let the user of the library to dig about these problems. Maybe it's better to face the problem inside the library, for example creating a folder and then delete it at the end, or simply registering created files and delete them and not all files in temp dir.

Comment: The files _should_ be shared between runs of the library, that's the main point of having the temporary directory, otherwise it would be unnecessary. Maybe clearing files interval should be much larger than the default 1 hour. Recommending different temp directories between applications should mitigate runs in different periods etc.